# SLURM node assignment order not always following Weight setting

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

We have a small cluster of 25 nodes running Slurm, of which the nodes can fall into a number of categories, as all the nodes are not the same. We have bigger/powerful nodes, and small/weak nodes.
All these nodes are, for the most part, basically in one partition, and we use the various job request settings for specifying which node(s) a job gets.
We also use the **Weight** setting on all the nodes, so that small jobs are to go to the small/weak nodes first, and not take space on the bigger nodes.
And here is the problem: If the nodes are *on*, (we use Slurm's power saving feature to switch unused nodes off) it works as expected. A small job goes to a small node.
However, if the nodes are *off*, (there are no nodes that can take it currently on) the node assigned seems to ignore the Weight setting, and seems to go where-ever. **A small job may end up assigned to and switching on a big node.** It seems to show the most when some nodes are on, but in use, and other nodes are off.
Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: UPDATE:
We never got this resolved. However, as the cluster has now expanded to over 80 nodes and usage is so much higher, we have disabled the power saving feature, so all nodes are on at all times. As stated above, when nodes are on they work correctly. So, this effectively fixes the issue without fixing it.